# Filter DataGridView items by properties of objects on a List in an item property

Tags: c#, devexpress, maui

Sorry for the confusing title, will clear it up now. I have a `DataGridView` (DevExpress) in a XAML MAUI application.

```
<dxg:DataGridView x:Name="ArticlesGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ArticlesToChooseFrom}"
              FilterString="{Binding GridFilter}"
              IsColumnHeaderVisible="False" SelectionMode="None">
              ...
</dxg:DataGridView>
```

The items are fed from a ViewModel property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Article> ArticlesToChooseFrom { get; private set; }
```

The Article class contains the property:

```
public List<ArticleAltName> AltNames { get; set; }
```

The ArticleAltName class contains the property `Name`.

When the `FilterString` property of the DataGridView changes it call a method in the ViewModel which changes the filter query string:

```
GridFilter = $"Contains([ArticleName], '{searchText}')";
```

**How can I filter artiles by their `AltNames`?**

First I thought I could access the child properties with the dot operator:

```
GridFilter = $"Contains([ArticleName], '{searchText}') or Contains([AltCodes.AltNames.Name], '{searchText}')";
```

...but the `AltNames` property contains a `List<>` instead of a reference to a single object.

Comment: What's the code of `AltCodes`, `ArticleName` and `Name`? Could you please post the code of the MVVM and file `.xaml` of your page so that we can help you better?